# sql update table from different columns of another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

### Table1

```
S/N  OnId    FromDate      ToDate      Value  
aaa   1     2010-10-09    2010-10-15     ?  
aaa   2     2010-10-10    2010-10-29     ?  
bbb   1     2010-10-16    2010-10-20     ?
```

### Table2

```
Id     Date          Count  
1     2010-10-03     100  
2     2010-10-03     150  
1     2010-10-08     200  
2     2010-10-12     250  
1     2010-10-13     300  
1     2010-10-14     400  
2     2010-10-17     450  
1     2010-10-20     500
```

I need to find the most recent Count from Table2 with the same Id and a Date less than FromDate (call it 'FromCount'), and the most recent Count with the same Id and a Date less than ToDate (call it 'ToCount'), and update the Value column in Table1 with their difference. So the intermediate calculation would look like this:

```
S/N  OnId    FromDate      ToDate      FromCount  ToCount
aaa   1     2010-10-09    2010-10-15      200       400   
aaa   2     2010-10-10    2010-10-29      150       450  
bbb   1     2010-10-16    2010-10-20      400       500
```

and after the UPDATE, Table1 would look like this:

### Table1

```
S/N  OnId    FromDate      ToDate      Value  
aaa   1     2010-10-09    2010-10-15     200 (400-200)   
aaa   2     2010-10-10    2010-10-29     300 (450-150)  
bbb   1     2010-10-16    2010-10-20     100 (500-400)
```

Afterwards I will need to summerize all the values for same S/N :

### Table3

```
S/N    Total
aaa     500
bbb     100
```

I use sql server 2005 and hope to succeed using sql and will not need to write all
this in my application in c# :)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Leon, are you stuck on a particular step, or do you need help getting started, or do you want the whole solution?

Comment: It's really not quite clear which rows you want to select in which case..... can you elaborate a bit more?? For `S/N=aaa` and `OnId=1` - which two rows from table 2 do you select and why those two??

Comment: For S/N=aaa and OnId=1 rows 6 and 3. i need to calculate the difference of counts between FromDate and ToDate. For 2010-10-15 the latest Count is from 2010-10-14 (line 6) and for 2010-10-09 the latest count is for 2010-10-8 (line 3). I know how to get the latest count with SELECT (TOP 1)...WHERE (date>=FromDate) ORDER BY DATE DESC  but i don't know how to do it both for FromDate and ToDate for calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
 UPDATE table1  
 SET Value =   
 (
    isnull( 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Count 
        FROM table2 t2To 
        WHERE t2To.Id = t1.OnId AND t2To.Date <= t1.ToDate 
        ORDER BY t2To.Date DESC) 
    ,0.0)
 )-(
    isnull(
       (SELECT TOP 1 Count 
        FROM table2 t2To 
        WHERE t2To.Id = t1.OnId AND t2To.Date <= t1.FromDate 
        ORDER BY t2To.Date DESC) 
    ,0.0)
 )
```

Thanks!

Comment: use isnull(test_value, what_if_null_value) or coalesce(test_value1, test_value2, test_value3 ..... test_valueN). And if this works, accept the answer.

Comment: THanks! Can u tell me pls how can i see values of declared variables in query window of sql server 2005 just for debug?

Answer (score 1):

You need two [correlated subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx):

Here's a query with one subquery:

```
SELECT t1.SN, t1.OnId, t1.FromDate, t1.ToDate,
      (SELECT TOP 1 Count
       FROM table2 t2To
       WHERE t2To.Id = t1.OnId AND t2To.Date <= t1.ToDate
       ORDER BY t2To.Date DESC)
FROM table1 t1
```

That gives you this:

```
aaa         1   2010-10-09    2010-10-15    400  
aaa         2   2010-10-10    2010-10-29    450  
bbb         1   2010-10-16    2010-10-20    500
```

You need to add the other one, and then turn it into an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Value = 
   (SELECT ...) - (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question because two instances of count are required (one for "from" and one for "to") but its definitely heading in the right direction

Comment: this looks ugly. Subqueries in subqueries in update? My professor used to say in this case "if you've reached a depth of 3, then surely you've done something wrong, or it's a hell of a query in a hell of a database". This doesn't seem like a hell of a database. I'll analyze this later (no time now). If I can't come up with something better, than I was wrong here :).

Comment: @Murph: No, I know - I've got a complete solution but I figure it's better to give helping hand in the right direction. Give a man a fish, etc...

Comment: @Alexander: It's not nested to three levels, it's 'nested' to one level: UPDATE ... SET Value = <subequery1> - <subquery2> Admittedly there are two subqueries, but they're only there to calculate the two values; they're not nested.

Comment: @Alexander: which is not to say that there isn't a better way to do it than subqueries, just that my method doesn't use nested subqueries.

Comment: @gkrogers - quite agree about it being better to give a helping hand - but if you only give a partial answer you need to be explicit about it because its not obvious (we have no way to discern intent from simply looking at the page)

Comment: @gkrogers, got some time to read and understand the question thoroughly. My apologies, I guess your answer's right. Could be done in some different ways, but with the same complexity. +1 for a good answer